# Virtualenv is not being activated from supervisord AWS Elasticbeanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, supervisord

I am trying to deploy my Django Channels app to elastic beanstalk and to start daphne and workers on deployment I have a supervisord script that gets copied and restarted during deployment. Some odd behavior is happening detailed below.

This is my channels.config file that gets run during deployment

```
container_commands:
  01_copy_supervisord_conf:
    command: "cp .ebextensions/supervisord/supervisord.conf /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf"
  02_reload_supervisord:
    command: "supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf reload"
```

When I just have this in my supervisord.conf

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/opt/python/run/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
;chmod=0700                 ; socket file mode (default 0700)
;chown=nobody:nogroup       ; socket file uid:gid owner

[supervisord]
logfile=/opt/python/log/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
logfile_maxbytes=10MB        ; (max main logfile bytes b4 rotation;default 50MB)
logfile_backups=10           ; (num of main logfile rotation backups;default 10)
loglevel=info                ; (log level;default info; others: debug,warn,trace)
pidfile=/opt/python/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
minfds=1024                  ; (min. avail startup file descriptors;default 1024)
minprocs=200                 ; (min. avail process descriptors;default 200)
directory=/opt/python/current/app    ; (default is not to cd during start)
;nocleanup=true              ; (don't clean up tempfiles at start;default false)

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///opt/python/run/supervisor.sock

[program:httpd]
command=/opt/python/bin/httpdlaunch
numprocs=1
directory=/opt/python/current/app
autostart=true
autorestart=unexpected
startsecs=1                   ; number of secs prog must stay running (def. 1)
startretries=3                ; max # of serial start failures (default 3)
exitcodes=0,2                 ; 'expected' exit codes for process (default 0,2)
killasgroup=false             ; SIGKILL the UNIX process group (def false)
redirect_stderr=false
```

The EB deploys fine (although daphne and a worker are not started and running yet)

If I add this to my supervisord.conf file:

```
[program:Daphne]
environment=PATH="/opt/python/run/venv/bin"
command=/opt/python/run/venv/bin/daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 5000 chat.asgi:channel_layer
directory=/opt/python/current/app
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/tmp/daphne.out.log
```

Then the deployment fails with this error:

```
error: , : file: /usr/lib64/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py line: 800
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/01flip.py", line 42, in 
main()
File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/01flip.py", line 36, in main
config.restart_apache()
File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/config.py", line 250, in restart_apache
apache_cmd('restart', should_be_running=True)
File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/config.py", line 254, in apache_cmd
check_call('/usr/local/bin/supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf %s httpd' % command, shell=True)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 541, in check_call
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '/usr/local/bin/supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf restart httpd' returned non-zero exit status 2.
```

but If i ssh into the instance than ps -aux | less I can see daphne is actually running.

Then if I add this into supervisord.conf:

```
[program:Worker]
environment=PATH="/opt/python/run/venv/bin"
command=python manage.py runworker
directory=/opt/python/current/app
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
numprocs=4
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/tmp/workers.out.log
```

it again fails to deploy with the same error but when I check the workers.out.log logs I see

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Which means its not using the environment part of the Worker program?

Not sure where to go wrong here. I have tried looking around to see how to activate a virtualenv through supervisord but come up with exactly what I am already doing.

**Edit 1**
So I was able to fix the deploying problem where it fails to deploy by including a shell script in my project with this:

```
#!/bin/bash
VENV=$1
if [ -z $VENV ]; then
    echo "usage: runinenv [virtualenv_path] CMDS"
    exit 1
fi
. ${VENV}/bin/activate
```

and this in my supervisord.conf file:

```
[program:runvenv]
command=sh virtualenv-sh /opt/python/run/venv
directory=/opt/python/current/app
stdout_logfile=/tmp/venv.out.log
```

It successfully deploys, daphne is still running but when i check the worker.out.log file it is still giving me the same error about django not being installed and to make sure I have the virtualenv activated. Which I just did? Unless that was not persistent after the one call?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem of workers not starting, but I was able to fix it by replacing:

```
command=python manage.py runworker
```

with

```
command=/opt/python/run/venv/bin/python manage.py runworker
```

I guess without the path it didn't use virtualenv when starting the worker.